# how to make the game save the best score with if statement javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am building a simple game as practice that counts the number of taps pressed in 3 seconds i have done everything apart from making it able to save the record score and if there is no record score then to show the old record.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript1.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="firstcss.css">
</head>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="div1">
        <button onclick="myFunction()" id="something">GO
        </button>
    </div>
    <div id="div2">
        <p id="paragraph">0</p>
    </div>
    <p id="don"></p>
    <p id="record"></p>
    <p id="add"></p>
    <script>
        var cool = 1;
        var red = 0;

        function myFunction() {
            document.getElementById("something").innerHTML = "Keep Tapping";
            document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML = cool;
            cool++;
            var parent = document.getElementById("div1");
            setTimeout(function() {
                var ooo = cool - 1;
                document.getElementById("don").innerHTML = ooo;
                var parent = document.getElementById("div1");
                var child = document.getElementById("something");
                parent.removeChild(child);
                var parent1 = document.getElementById("div2");
                var child1 = document.getElementById("paragraph");
                parent1.removeChild(child1);

                if (cool - 1 > red) {
                    var red = cool - 1;
                    document.getElementById("record").innerHTML = red;
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("record").innerHTML = red;
                    document.getElementById("add").innerHTML = red;
                }

            }, 3000);
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I am using the if statement at the end but want to know how you would save the high score or if there isnt one to say the old high score. thanks it would be really helpful.

Comment: What do you mean by "save" the high score?

Comment: You have to figure out where to save it first: do you have a backend web service you can send it to, or do you want to store it in HTML 5 local storage?  Is this a phonegap project, or web site?

Comment: I want to store it to html 5 local storage @BrianMains

Comment: u can save that score in local file or database through ajax call or php... should i write code of that for you. Or u want to learn that

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following resources on local storage:

- http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage

Essentially you can do (taken from the Dive int HTML 5 link):

```
var foo = localStorage.getItem("bar");
// ...
localStorage.setItem("bar", foo);
```